# Is there a way to refer a single swagger schema in Readme.io docs?

Tags: swagger, documentation, openapi, readme, readme.io

In our public documentation, we've linked swagger endpoints to Readme documentation.
But is there a way to import and refer to a single Schema entity, for example, Address in this case (swagger):
[image]

For now, the only way to use this Address object is to open it as body params like so (readme)
[image]

Ideally good to have a direct link to this data object like https://<my_project>.readme.io/reference/<my_endpoint>#Address.